# Google picker API error: Server IP address n-utbhwlxa4witl3o3ev4uschzd37oxgge2qt73xy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com was not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-picker

I have a problem with running Google picker API.

I'm trying to make a custom menu function for my Google spreadsheet that I can choose a file with (obtain file ID on Google Drive) and then my apps-script will automatically rename it according to result in some cell in sheet and then it will also move the file to a proper folder on Google Drive. I think I'm able to do everything mentioned above except to run Google picker API.

To do task described above I think I need Google Picker API. **Please correct me if I'm wrong!!! I just need a dialog window which will let me choose a file and let give me file ID of the chosen file.**

So basically I have followed instructions for File-open dialogs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) and [here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). I've tried it many many times. I've tried every help I could find on youtube or google, but the result is still the same:

When I open my spreadsheet, I see my new custom menu, I open it and click on Start which runs the script. The script opens a blank window with "Select a file". After a while I get this statement:[image]

> The statement means "Server IP address n-utbhwlxa4witl3o3ev4uschzd37oxgge2qt73xy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com was not found" (Address looks like Client ID, but it's definiteliy not the ID i see in web console.)

I've enabled Google Picker Api and Google drive API in developers console, I've also copied API_KEY to the code. I think I've done everything described in instuctions right. But I've done nothing more. I'm afraid that I'm missing some basic step which is obvious for skilled developer, but I've no clue. (Like if I have to specify Authorized JavaScript origins for OAuth 2.0 client IDs etc.)

Anybody any idea or direction, please?

EDIT:
My .gs code is (copy-pasted from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs):

```
    /**
     * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
     */
    function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
          .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
          .addToUi();
    }

    /**
     * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
     * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
     */
    function showPicker() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('filepicker.html')
          .setWidth(600)
          .setHeight(425)
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
     * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
     * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
     * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
     * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
     * in the user's Drive.
     *
     * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      DriveApp.getRootFolder();
      return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    }
```

and my html code (also copy-pasted from the same source) is as follows (I have not changed anything except Developers key):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'I put my own key here';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This website is dedicated to specific programming questions. Please share your code and describe the structure of your project. Trying to guess the error without the code is like fortune-telling.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response and advice. I edited my original post to make it easier for others to understand my problem. I'm not sure what do you mean by "stucture of my project". Do you mean Gogle Cloud Platform project or generally to describe a project? As long as I'm completely new here, I'm catching up to how it's going on here. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Nothing changes. Everything works the same way. Even the IP address in the error statement is still the same. Doesn't matter if the key is there or not at all, it still does the same thing. It seems to me like the javascript is trying to open the picker via wrong address (or client ID).

Comment: Maybe a lame question, but just to be sure: Do I have to be G Suits subscriber or should the Google picker work with also free account? Although the article about Picker isn't listed under Extend G Suite, there is G Suite mentioned in the title. But if so, why would console etc. let me activate everything like in instructions.

Comment: @ZdeněkFrank , could you try changing the following bit in your 'showPicker' function HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('filepicker.html')  to HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('filepicker').evaluate().

Comment: Also, try this - in Chrome browser, open the Developer Tools while inside the sheet. Navigate to the Network tab. Press CMD + R (probably  Ctrl + R in Windows) to reload the document and start recording network activity. Click on the menu item to load the dialog. Watch the data being recorded. Locate the entry called 'userCodeAppPanel' and click on it.  http://prntscr.com/kcttgu Examine the response headers and make sure the status code is 200. If it isn't, there might be an issue with your network.

Comment: @ZdeněkFrank No, you don't have to be a G Suite subscriber to use the Picker API as I have it running on my free Gmail account

Comment: I had tried "HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('filepicker').evaluate()" already before with no luck.

Comment: But your next() advice got me further! :-) Status is OK, but I found there different error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCmaImaIxwUlm0-HYSwMx5UyxGFHInWF/view?usp=sharing So I tried to open my sheets in Microsoft Edge and the picker worked there. So THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I'll try to reinstall chrome, because I think the error can be caused by some removed Chrome add-od (I removed already all of them except Google documents offline.)

Comment: What cofuses me is that I tried to open my spreadsheet and run picker on two different computers under different google accounts, so I didn't suspect Chrome... If you have an idea how to fix it without Chrome reinstalation, please let me know, I'd be grateful. If you paste your post as the answer to my question, I'l mark it solved even if you dont know final solution of my problem. At least I know there is no problem with my code. That is sufficient for me for now.

Comment: @ZdeněkFrank sorry, would you like me to post my previous comment as the new solution? The screenshot probably doesn't have anything do to with the issue as I get the same 'transport error' thrown in the console, but the Picker does work in Chrome. Have you tried clearing application cache and deleting cookies? if the issue persists across different Chrome instances on different computers, it's probably network related

Comment: @AntonDementiev I'll leave it up to you. It was not exactly the final answer, but at least it led me to find the solution. It had nothing to do with code. It was browsers cache and some add-ons what was causing the problem. Later I found out on web help forums that many other users have similar issues like I had and a lot of them were solved by clearing a cache or uninstalling some addons. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Amit Agarwal wrote a [tutorial on this blog](https://ctrlq.org/code/20039-google-picker-with-apps-script) about using Picker API in Apps Script.

Here's a snippet:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Google Picker')
      .addItem('Choose Folder', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select Folder');
}

function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had tried this one already. I had googled everything I coul findbefore asking here. For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z9QOx8qrW0 with no luck. I even made completly new google account for testing to be sure that I didn't accidentally click on something and didnt't turn it on or off...